# Builds uploaded and accepted into Internal Testing and Closed Testing tracks but don't show up in testing devices

Tags: google-play, google-play-games, google-play-internal-testing

As the tittle says, we have uploaded our builds to internal and closed testing (for good measure) and they should be available for testing on our devices, but, the only an older build appears in the play store.

Has anyone had this problem before? If so, how did you get it working again?

Thank you for the attention!
Kind Regards,
João rodrigues

So:
1- New internal release created
2- Build uploaded and set to internal testing
3- On our mobile devices we open the internal testing link, accept the invite
4- Open the play store, navigate to the app
5- See internal testing after the name of the app
6- Check the release date of the build and it's from January and not the most recent build we just uploaded. Even after waiting for days and clearing data/cache of the play store, using more than 10 differnet devices with different android versions it stays the same. Even after contacting Google they haven't been able to present us with a solution.